# Styling every other div that has a particular class

Tags: jquery, html, css, layout

I'm working on a form that contains both half size and full size inputs.

The mid sized inputs will come in pairs and the second will float right/be push right with a margin.

```
<form>
<h3>Title</h3>
<div class="mid">
    <label>blah</label>
    <input type="text">
</div>
<div class="mid">
    <label>blah</label>
    <input type="text">
</div>

<div class="full">
    <label>blah</label>
    <input type="text">
</div>

<div class="mid">
    <label>blah</label>
    <input type="text">
</div>
<div class="mid">
    <label>blah</label>
    <input type="text">
</div>
</form>
```

I was using CSS3 "form .mid:nth-child(odd)", however, as I have the h3, it is not looking at the correct element.

Is there a way I can automate this process either with CSS or jQuery, rather than having to add a class to every other item by hand?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you show it in http://jsfiddle.net/ (not just html but with css)?

Comment: Sure, I probably should have said too; The form isn't necessarily fixed with this layout, it could any of the sizes e.g. 'full' 'full' 'mid' 'mid' 'mid' 'mid'.

http://jsfiddle.net/Qg2uM/

Comment: @jonnow I don't think you can do it with css since there's no `nth-of-class` selector, but you can do it using jQuery. See if my answer solves it for you, I'm not sure if I misunderstood the question, though

Comment: That's the one yes, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible using only CSS, unfortunately there's no `nth-of-class` selector.

You could do it using jQuery's [`:odd`](https://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/) selector:

```
$('form div.mid').filter(':odd').addClass('someClass');
```

This way, you're only working on the collection of elements that you want.

Also note:

> In particular, note that the 0-based indexing means that,
> counter-intuitively, :odd selects the second element, fourth element,
> and so on within the matched set.

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9J844/)

Answer (score -1):

You could try something like that

```
form div:nth-child(3n+1)
```

An example : http://jsfiddle.net/nUu6M/

This will trigger every .full input field without use any class